# How does this ItemsContainerStyle know about ItemsControl.AlternationIndex

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I've been reading through WPF Unleashed and something has confused me about styles.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Control}" x:Key="altStyle">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" ></Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" ></Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

So I have a style here which can be applied to anything that derives from control. Assuming that's how the TargetType works. The confusing part for me is how it understands what `ItemsControl.AlternationIndex` is. I'm defining a style for a control, which is higher up the inheritance chain than ItemsControl. It's seems to break the rules of inheritance.

I then have a simple datagrid which uses this style as its ItemsContainerStyle:

```
<local:MyGrid AlternationCount="2" ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=DataContext.Source}" Grid.Row="3" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource altStyle}"></local:MyGrid>
```

(MyGrid derives from DataGrid)

I'm assuming here that the style is applied to each DataRow in the grid, but how on earth is able to resolve this `ItemsControl.AlternationIndex` as this certainly does not apply to a DataRow does it? and just for clarity on how it looks:

[image]

So the question is. How does a style that applies to a datagrid row manage to resolve a property called `ItemsControl.AlternationIndex`

Comment: It's an attached property set against item container when it's created

Comment: @dkozl Ah I see, so it's working similar to a Grid.Row property in that it looks to be set against the grid, but it's not really. So each gridrow does have an alternationindex, just I can only access it through the static alternationindex attached property

Comment: Attached property, like any other `DependencyProperty`, can be set against any `DependencyObject`. Which means that you can set a property value against object that does not define this property. `DependencyObject` can store value for any `DependencyProperty` so you can add functionality to already existing objects. Each `ItemsControl` sets `ItemsControl.AlternationIndex` against its item container (`ContentPresenter`, `ListBoxItem`, `ListViewItem`, `DataGridRow` and so on) when it's created

Comment: Like the example you mentioned. There is no need to define `Column` and `Row` property for each object when it's only needed when it's a child of a `Grid` panel. Same with `DockPanel.Dock`. No need to define it against each object just in case it may be the child of `DockPanel`. It can be attached later where it's needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an [attached property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms749011%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) the [`AlternationIndex`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.alternationindex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) can be set on any dependency object and can potentially be inherited. When the style queries the rows it will find that the attached property has been set on them by the creating `ItemsControl` (the grid control).